# RecyclerView change selected item background and text color

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-relativelayout

I am using `RecyclerView.` I tried to change background color in item click with `selector.xml` file.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/trains_vagon_selected_departure" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/trains_vagon_selected_departure" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/trains_vagon_selected_white" />
</selector>
```

**Adapter code:**

```
public class TrainsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    public ArrayList<Train> trains;
    public Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String statusString = "";

    public TrainsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Train> trains, String statusString) {
        this.context = context;
        this.trains = trains;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.statusString = statusString;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trains_adapter_item, parent, false);
        GenericViewHolder holder = new GenericViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof GenericViewHolder) {
            final GenericViewHolder genericViewHolder = (GenericViewHolder) holder;
            genericViewHolder.vagoncontainer.removeAllViews();
            Train train = trains.get(position);
            if (statusString.equals("departure"))
                genericViewHolder.statusImageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.departure_icon);
            else
                genericViewHolder.statusImageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.return_icon);
            ArrayList<Vagons> vagons = train.getVagons();
            for (int i = 0; i < vagons.size(); i++) {
                if (vagons.get(i).getEnable().equals("1")) {
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    final LinearLayout vagonView = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.trains_vagon_child, null);
                    genericViewHolder.vagoncontainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) vagonView.findViewById(R.id.selected_layout);

                    if (statusString.equals("departure"))
                        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recyclerview_selected_departure);
                    else
                        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recyclerview_selected_returned);

                    TextView vagonClassName = (TextView) vagonView.findViewById(R.id.vagon_class_name);
                    TextView vagonClassPrice = (TextView) vagonView.findViewById(R.id.vagon_class_price);
                    vagonClassName.setText(vagons.get(i).getName());
                    vagonClassPrice.setText(vagons.get(i).getAmount());

                    genericViewHolder.vagoncontainer.addView(vagonView);
                }
            }

            genericViewHolder.trainTime.setText(train.getDeparture());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return trains.size();
    }

    public Train getItem(int position) {
        return trains.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class GenericViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView trainTime;
        public LinearLayout vagoncontainer;
        private ImageView statusImageView;

        public GenericViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            trainTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.train_time);
            statusImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.departure_next_img);

            vagoncontainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.vagon_container);
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions.

1) When I run first element in `RecyclerView` also selected automatically. Why? How can I fix it?

2) Is it a possible to change text color inside selector `xml` file?
I know how to change simple recyclerView's background and text color by position, but at the moment each elements by position has some array's and I added it my position and I tried to change child's view background and text color(please see my code. I mean vagonView view)

thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

its may be due to come selected when you run app because of on `state_focus="true"`.

Comment: You are right but when i wrote default false ,then focus not working in all time @Hasmukh kachhatiya

Comment: then you have to try `state_pressed="true"`

Comment: I tried it and first time first element auto selected @Hasmukh kachhatiya

Comment: can you continue in chat ? @ Hasmukh kachhatiya

Answer (score 0):

1. How do you know the first element is selected ?
2. Just set `android:textColor` with some color state list

Comment: 1) when i run first element is already selected 2) what do you mean? can you explain more? @Cesario

Comment: for 2. suppose you have a TextView, the set `textColor` to some color statelist (selector xml), but you need to create another `xml` for the text color